# Spring Security ACL Domains Error: The type xxx is already defined

Tags: eclipse, grails, spring-security, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse, Grails 2.4.5 and the [Spring Security ACL plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-acl). I created the domain classes that manage ACL data with the command:

```
s2-create-acl-domains
```

After these domains have been generated Eclipse reports that the classes have already been defined.

[image]

The error log shows:

[image]

In my `BuildConfig.groovy` I have:

```
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC5"
runtime ':spring-security-acl:2.0-RC2'
```

**Is there a way to fix this that Eclipse does not show the errors? Beside that error the code is running fine.**

Edit: Here are the classes which are generated by `grails s2-create-acl-domains`. I did not change anything except in `AclObjectIdentity` objectId type from Long to String.

Here are the classes which have been generated:

`AclClass`:

```
package grails.plugin.springsecurity.acl

class AclClass {

    String className

    @Override
    String toString() {
        "AclClass id $id, className $className"
    }

    static mapping = {
        className column: 'class'
        version false
    }

    static constraints = {
        className unique: true, blank: false
    }
}
```

`AclObjectIdentity`:

```
package grails.plugin.springsecurity.acl

class AclObjectIdentity extends AbstractAclObjectIdentity {

    String objectId

    @Override
    String toString() {
        "AclObjectIdentity id $id, aclClass $aclClass.className, " +
        "objectId $objectId, entriesInheriting $entriesInheriting"
    }

    static mapping = {
        version false
        aclClass column: 'object_id_class'
        owner column: 'owner_sid'
        parent column: 'parent_object'
        objectId column: 'object_id_identity'
    }

    static constraints = {
        objectId unique: 'aclClass'
    }
}
```

`AclSid`:

```
package grails.plugin.springsecurity.acl

class AclSid {

    String sid
    boolean principal

    @Override
    String toString() {
        "AclSid id $id, sid $sid, principal $principal"
    }

    static mapping = {
        version false
    }

    static constraints = {
        principal unique: 'sid'
        sid blank: false, size: 1..255
    }
}
```

`AclEntry`:

```
package grails.plugin.springsecurity.acl

class AclEntry {

    AclObjectIdentity aclObjectIdentity
    int aceOrder
    AclSid sid
    int mask
    boolean granting
    boolean auditSuccess
    boolean auditFailure

    @Override
    String toString() {
        "AclEntry id $id, aceOrder $aceOrder, mask $mask, granting $granting, " +
        "aclObjectIdentity $aclObjectIdentity"
    }

    static mapping = {
        version false
        sid column: 'sid'
        aclObjectIdentity column: 'acl_object_identity'
    }

    static constraints = {
        aceOrder unique: 'aclObjectIdentity'
    }
}
```

**Edit: I still have no SOLUTION for this problem!!!**

Answer (score 3):

Groovy has two ways to treat a .groovy file:

- **as a script** : In this case you can not have a class by the same name as the file. You can recognize script file, if there is any code outside a class statement in the file (other than imports), it is a script
- **as a class definition file**: of course as in Java you will have the class definition as the same name as your file.

What is happening in the script case is that if there is any code to be executed in the file then Groovy needs a containing class for that code. Groovy will implicitly create a containing class with the name of the file.

So if you have a file called AclEntry.groovy that has some code in it that isn't inside a class definition, Groovy will create an implicit containing class called AclEntry. This means that the script file AclEntry.groovy can not itself contain a class called AclEntry because that would be a duplicate class definition, thus the error.

If, on the other hand, all you do in the file AclEntry.groovy is define the class AclEntry (and any number of other classes), then Groovy will treat that file as simply a collection of class definitions, there will be no implicit containing class, and there is no problem having a class called AclEntry inside the class definition file AclEntry.groovy.

you might want to check if this is the case in your groovy files.

Comment: The only command I executed was ``grails s2-create-acl-domains``. I posted the generated classes in my edit. Please could you have a look and tell me what I should change to make it work?

Comment: looks like its an eclipse issue only, what I would try is 1) delete the build directory of eclipse and see if it helps ; or 2) create a new project, imported in eclipse and copy your groovy files in this project; eclipse should not complain.

Comment: I use GGTS on Mac. Where do I find the build directory?

Comment: for a grails app, you can run `grails clean` or delete the `target` directory (the thing to do when nothing else works !)

Comment: Should I also delete the target-eclipse directory?

Comment: I did grails clean and deleted the target directory it did not help. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse may have old files in cache.

You can try the following:

```
grails clean.
```

Then reinstall the classes.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the assumption that you have installed the [Grails Spring Security Core](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) plugin and configured that correctly.

First a bit of background. Java cannot have classes that are referenced using the same name. Eclipse, via the groovy plugin, is complaining that classes with the names `AclClass, AclEntry, AclObjectIndentity, AclSid` are already defined. The frustration comes when you did not define those classes! The thing to remember with groovy is groovy implicitly defines classes based on script names. (See this [quick write up](https://www.moreofless.co.uk/invalid-duplicate-class-definition-error-groovy/) by Steve Claridge for more information.)

Since you are mentioning that the code runs I expect that [like this user](http://groovy-eclipse-plugin.42567.n3.nabble.com/incorrect-quot-The-type-mytype-is-already-defined-quot-flag-td862142.html) on the groovy mailing list, Eclipse is holding onto a class reference that is no longer there. The solution that worked for him was:

> Moving the class to a separate groovy class file made the error move
>   with the class; eclipse now complained that the class in the groovy
>   class file was already defined.
>
> However, I solved the problem like this:
>
> 1. Delete the class from the class file, and save that file.
> 2. Save the script file (without the class), then open it copy the class definition back in, and save the file again.
>
> --Eric Tiffany

This seems to reset the saved references that Eclipse has in memory.

**EDIT**:

[Here is a different tutorial for using Spring security with grails.](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/single.html#tutorials) The script will create a few sample classes for you with which to begin filling out an application. Try and follow those directions and see if the same error is being thrown.

Comment: I tried this. 1. Clean project, 2. remove generated domain > grails.plugin.springsecurity.acl > ... 3. Clean Project. 4. s2-create-acl-domains This leads to the same error. What did I wrong. Could you please post a sample project which I can test?

Comment: Your answer does not help anything. I read the manual of spring security and ACL.

Comment: Since your code is working I wonder if there is something wrong with the way Eclipse is configured. Have you tried using [Jetbrains Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/)? They have a free community edition. The community edition does not have many of the handy features for developing Grails that the Ultimate edition has but you can use the Grails command line interface and go from there.

Comment: This may be a hiccup within the eclipse plugin for groovy. I am updating my answer with a solution someone on the groovy mailing list used to solve a similar problem.

Comment: Again do not post links to the documentation I know all this stuff. Using s2-quickstart is not a revolutionarry answer. Come on.

Comment: @stephan1002, No need to be rude. Since you are new to SO (member for 40 days @ time of answer) I am going to point out that in the ["How do I write a good answer"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guide for Stack Overflow Links are encouraged as well as civility. I am a volunteer, just trying to help. If my answer does not help you in any way, it does not cost you anything.

Comment: I am not rude but I read before that I know all the documentation of Spring Security and ACL.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to refresh dependencies using grails [refresh-dependencies](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.3/ref/Command%20Line/refresh-dependencies.html) command.