# Spring Security ACL Inheriting: How does it really works?

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy, spring-security

I am using Spring Security with domain Level security (ACL).

I have two domains Company and Book.

```
class Company {
 String name
 hasMany = [books: Book]
}

class Book {
 String title
 belongsTo = [company: Company]
}
```

I read that an ACL can have a [Parent](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/acls/domain/AclImpl.html#getParentAcl()) where it inherits its permissions from.

In a service I would have a method like this to set permission for a new book card:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasPermission(#book, admin)")
void addPermission(Book book, String username, Permission permission) {
  aclUtilService.addPermission(book, username, permission)
}
```

This works fine and creates a permission for a new book instance. I also have an update method which checks the permission before the book can be updated.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#book, write) or hasPermission(#book, admin)")
Book update(Book book, Map params = [:]) {    
  book.properties = params
  book.save(flush:true) 
  return book
}
```

This works fine as long as the user has the permission for the book. But, I want to user the permission of the parent object (company) to be inherited to the book. When a user has permission to the company I want that it has also permission to all of the company's books.

I see in [AclImp](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/acls/domain/AclImpl.html#getParentAcl()) that there is a method `setParent()`. This works if you do:

```
AclImpl acl = aclUtilService.readAcl(book)
acl.setParent(aclUtilService.readAcl(book.company))
aclService.updateAcl(acl)
```

Using the code above will set the parent for book in the database.

**How do I use inheriting in Spring Security ACL?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this instead of playing with the parent ACL:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#book.company, write) or hasPermission(#book.company, admin)")
Book update(Book book, Map params = [:]) {    
  book.properties = params
  book.save(flush:true) 
  return book
}
```

If you would rather inherit from the parent ACL, make sure the child's `AclObjectIdentity` has `entriesInheriting` set to `true`, for example using the method `createAcl` below:

```
void createAcl(Class clazz, Long id, String sid, AclObjectIdentity parent) {
    clazz = ProxyUtils.unproxy(clazz)
    AclClass aclClass = AclClass.findOrSaveByClassName(clazz.name)
    AclSid ownerSid = AclSid.findOrSaveBySidAndPrincipal(sid, true)
    AclObjectIdentity oid = findOrCreateObjectIdentity(aclClass, ownerSid, id, parent, true)
}

AclObjectIdentity findOrCreateObjectIdentity(AclClass aclClass, AclSid ownerSid, Long id, AclObjectIdentity parent, boolean entriesInheriting) {
    assert aclClass, "aclClass is required"
    assert null != id, "id is required"

    AclObjectIdentity oid = AclObjectIdentity.findOrCreateByAclClassAndObjectId(aclClass, id)
    if (null == oid.id) {
        oid.entriesInheriting = entriesInheriting
        oid.owner = ownerSid
        oid.parent = parent
        oid.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    }
    oid
}
```

If the ACL is inheriting `@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#child, read)")` will return true if current user has read on parent's ACL

Comment: entriesInheriting is always set to true. The question is how will the permissions be inherited. How do I test inherited permissions?

Comment: How do you check inherited permissions in @PreAuthorize?

Comment: How would you lookup parent? What if parent is a ``class A extends B {}`` and the object identity is written for the superclass B. You do not want to create a new object identity for class A? How would you handle this?

Comment: Thank you. You may have an idea on this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31597897/unable-to-find-acl-information-for-object-identity-org-springframework-security